# List of classes as an argument for another class in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, arraylist

I'm somewhat new to flutter and I think I'm missing the correct syntax on 1 field. I have tried search for an example, but I think I am using the wrong words. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have 2 classes, jobs and tasks, where a job is made up of many tasks.

```
class Job {
  int jobID;
  //List task_list; this is where I am having issues
  String imgageURL
  String jobName;

  Job({
   this.jobId,
   this.task_list,
   this.imageURL,
   this.jobName,
  });

} 

class Task{
   int taskID;
   String imageURL;
   String name;
   String type;
   int taskTime;

  Task({
    this.taskID,
    this.imageURL,
    this.name,
    this.type,
    this.taskTime,
  })
}
```

I tried defining all tasks and then assigning them to a list, but I am unsure on passing this to a Job. I want to the list to be growable as some jobs will have more tasks. But for now I just added 3.

```
final List<Task> all_tasks= [_task1,_task2,_task3];
```

Ultimately I want to be able to pass all data from assigned tasks to it's parent job so it can be accessed in the job as needed. I thought about adding all the fields to the tasks and just have a list of tasks, but I am going to assign some more fields to jobs that would then be duplicated in every task, which seems wasteful.

Is it possible to do a list within the job class or an array? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there; I think this should work:

```
class Job {
  int jobID;
  List<Task> task_list;
  String imageURL;
  String jobName;

  Job({
   this.jobId,
   this.task_list,
   this.imageURL,
   this.jobName,
  });

} 

class Task{
   int taskID;
   String imageURL;
   String name;
   String type;
   int taskTime;

  Task({
    this.taskID,
    this.imageURL,
    this.name,
    this.type,
    this.taskTime,
  })
}

final int myId = 1234;
final List<Task> all_tasks= [_task1,_task2,_task3];
final String myUrl = 'www.stackoverflow.com';
final String myJobName = 'developer';
final Job myJob = Job(myId, all_tasks, myUrl, myJobName);
```

The typing of a List can be virtually any class; just put it between the <>. If the list elements can be of variable type, you can use List.